# How to enable/disable dropdown with angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Hope it is not a duplicate question. I have some layout which is as follows,

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Category <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu default-dropdown">
         <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
   </ul> 
 </div>
```

How to enable dropdown on button click with angular?

Comment: Do you mean open/close or enable/disable?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer sorry open close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable/disable

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button [attr.disabled]="dropdownDisabled ? true : null" 
            type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Category <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu default-dropdown">
         <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
   </ul> 
 </div>

 <button (click)="dropdownDisabled = !dropdownDisabled">toggle</button>
```

to open/close

i assume that you're using bootstrap css style

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown" [class.open]="dropdownOpened">
    <button (click)="dropdownOpened = !dropdownOpened"
            type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" 
            data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" 
            [attr.aria-expanded]="dropdownOpened ? 'true': 'false' ">
    Category <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu default-dropdown">
         <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
   </ul> 
 </div>
```

Comment: i think he wanna do some act like bootstrap dropdown(open/close dropdown)

Comment: @TiepPhan thanks. Seems I took the question to literally :D

Comment: i made a change in your code, based on bootstrap css style

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Nothing happens when i added the code. anything to do with the component.ts?

Comment: @Sajeetharan did you take the changes of Tiep Phan into account?

Comment: @Sajeetharan add this in your .ts file `dropdownOpened: boolean = false;`

Comment: @TiepPhan any idea whenever i open the page dropdown is opened by default.

Comment: change `dropdownOpened: boolean = false;` to `dropdownOpened: boolean = true;`

Comment: I think `[attr.aria-expanded]="dropdownOpened ? 'true': 'false' "` needs to be `[attr.aria-expanded]="dropdownOpened ? true: null"`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer for some reason that is not working

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer [attr.aria-expanded]="dropdownOpened ? 'true': 'false' " needs to be [attr.aria-expanded]="dropdownOpened ? true: null" i made this change, it dint work

Comment: You mean the dropdown is still opened on page load? or what do you mean with "didn't work"?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes still opened, when i went and check the css display:block is set. after i disable it. it works well. but how to set by default?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134910/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: It seems Tiep Phan`s version was correct. I reverted it but http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/ uses `show` class instead of `open` - I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't know.

Comment: Why aren't you using https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap instead?

Comment: can you revert your answer to the previous one? it was working upto some extent if i disable display:block manually

Comment: What Bootstrap version are you using? Why are you not using ng-bootstrap?